# How do I extract the first 3 consonates from a string field SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

how can I extract from a field in records that contain names only the first 3 consonants and if a name does not have 3 consonants it adds the first vowel of the name?

For example, if I had the following record in the People table:

```
Field:Name
VALUE:Richard result=> RCH

FIELD:Name
VALUE:Paul  result=> PLA
```

Comment: What do you expect in case of 'Anny'? 'NNY' or 'NNA'? Are you considering 'Y' as a consonant or vowel here?

Comment: Also hyphen names are very funny examples :) For example 'AVA-RAE'

Comment: In the case of the parore anny the 'y' I count it as consonate therefore 'NNY'

Answer (score 2):

Here's one option; read comments within code.

Sample data:

```
SQL> with test (name) as
  2    (select 'Richard' from dual union all
  3     select 'Paul'    from dual
  4    ),
```

Query begins here:

```
  5  temp as
  6    -- val1 - consonants; val2 - vowels
  7    (select
  8       name,
  9       translate(upper(name), '#AEIOU', '#') val1,
 10       translate(upper(name), '#BCDFGHJKLMNPQRSTWXYZ', '#') val2
 11     from test
 12    )
 13  -- finally: if there are enough consonants (val1's length is >= 3), return the first 3
 14  -- letters (that's WHEN).
 15  -- Otherwise, add as many vowels as necessary (that's what ELSE does)
 16  select name,
 17    case when length(val1) >= 3 then substr(val1, 1, 3)
 18         else val1 || substr(val2, 1, 3 - length(val1))
 19    end result
 20  from temp;

NAME    RESULT
------- --------------
Richard RCH
Paul    PLA

SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for fun using regexp:

```
select
  name
 ,substr(
    regexp_replace(
       upper(name)
      ,'^([AEIOU]*)([^AEIOU]*)([AEIOU]*)([^AEIOU]*)([AEIOU]*)([^AEIOU]*).*'
      ,'\2\4\6\1\3\5'
    ),1,3) as result
from test;
```

- `([AEIOU]*)`  - is a group of vowels, 0 or more characters
- `([^AEIOU]*)` - is a group of not-vowels (or consonants in this case), 0 or more characters
- so this regexp looks for a pattern `(vowels1)(consonants1)(vowels2)(consonants2)(vowels3)(consonants3)` and reorders it to `(consonants1)(consonants2)(consonants3)(vowels1)(vowels2)(vowels3)`
- then we just take first 3 characters from the reordered string

Full test case:

```
with test (name) as
   (select 'Richard' from dual union all
    select 'Paul'    from dual union all
    select 'Annete'  from dual union all
    select 'Anny'    from dual union all
    select 'Aiua'    from dual union all
    select 'Isaiah'  from dual union all
    select 'Sue'     from dual
   )
select
  name
 ,substr(
    regexp_replace(
       upper(name)
      ,'^([AEIOU]*)([^AEIOU]*)([AEIOU]*)([^AEIOU]*)([AEIOU]*)([^AEIOU]*).*'
      ,'\2\4\6\1\3\5'
    ),1,3) as result
from test;

NAME    RESULT
------- ------------
Richard RCH
Paul    PLA
Annete  NNT
Anny    NNY
Aiua    AIU
Isaiah  SHI
Sue     SUE

7 rows selected.
```

Comment: What is regexp and how does it work and if somehow that a method like regexp_str?

Comment: Regexp - also Regex - regular expression functions. In this case, an Oracle function `regexp_replace`

Comment: Excuse me as for me it is a new topic I would like to know how this query works and in the precise le regexp

Comment: For regular expressions you can start with https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression and then https://www.regular-expressions.info/

Comment: I have added an explanation to the answer

Comment: thank you very much for the explanation, if instead I wanted to take the consontant 1,3,4 always with the same reasoning that adds the first vowel in case of lack of consonant

Comment: Just change groups or use `substr(...,1,1)||substr(...,3,2)`

Comment: How would the order be when changing groups?